# Bootstrap 3 Datepicker primer dia del mes

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, asp.net-mvc

Estoy usando el DataPicker de bootstrap3, pero no he podido establecer que inicie con el 1 del mes actual, he intentado muchas formar, aquí abajo una de ellas. Alguien lo ha hecho?

```
$(function() {
   $("#date_id").datepicker({ firstDay: 1 });
});
```

Comment: Hay muchas librerías de datepicker para bootstrap, ¿Podrías poner el link del que estás usando?

Answer (score 0):

Proba usar el evento [beforeShowDay](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay).

**Te dejo el ejemplo y la demo, espero que te sirva!**

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
beforeShowDay: function(date) {
    return [true, date.getDate() == 1 ? "first-class" : ""];
}
```

});

---

### La [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/Fs6uu/)